# Stongswan and Libreswan in Centos

Tags: centos7, ipsec, strongswan, libreswan

I have a server running stongswan with one VPN connection.

Can I add another VPN connection Via Libreswan on the same server?

So the server will run both Strongswan and Libreswan.

Regards,
Michael

Comment: What's the reason you want to mix IKE implementations?

Comment: No, but you can have Strongswan handle both connections.

Answer (score 1):

Generally not. First, IKE uses fixed UDP ports (500/4500) that both IKE daemons will want to bind their sockets to. Second, both IKE daemons will assume full control over the kernel's IPsec stack so there is a high chance for conflicts (e.g. duplicate reqids or policies).

You might be able to work around those issues (e.g. assign different ports, use static reqids, use network namespaces, or even use strongSwan's userland IPsec implementation), but you can probably avoid some headaches by sticking to one IKE implementation.